# Wordpress Flatsome theme (UX Builder) not saving changes

Tags: wordpress

I just installed the flatsome theme on WordPress on my namecheap server and I'm having a problem whereby the changes I make with the UX builder don't save. Every time I make changes and I click update then close the UX builder, the changes don't effect whereas when I make changes from WordPress "customize" it works.
I've tried several things, tried deleting and re-installing the theme, tried deleting and reinstalling WordPress itself, and still the same thing. Please I need help

Comment: Make sure that your new server doesn't have some aggressive caching installed. It may seem like stuff is not saved, because server may give you old pages. Try to turn off caching and see if the changes/pages are there. That said, if you see don't see your changes in wp-admin then it's probably not caching that is the problem. Check that your server software is compatible with the version of WordPress and the Flatsome theme.

Answer (score 0):

I can relate with you on this flatsome issues of not saving because I  also experienced the same issue....

I later solved it myself. View what you to see in the screenshot I sent here and make changes via your cpanel php extensions.

[image: click on dbase extension, PHP version 7.4 problem solved]

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same problem , i just updated the last version of flatsome and all is fine

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely contact flatsome uxthemes support for that.
They provide support for their theme.